# Why $H\neq \emptyset$ in Definition of Subgroup?

Tags: definition

The standard definition of a Subgroup $H$ of a Group $(G,+)$ is as follows:

> $H$ is Subgroup of $(G,+)$ if $\begin{cases} G \supseteq H\neq \emptyset \\ \forall x,y \in H:(x+y) \in H \\ \forall x \in H:(-x) \in H \end{cases}$

Why $H\neq \emptyset$?

Comment: Because a subgroup is a group in its own right, and groups are by definition nonempty (it must contain an identity element).

Comment: A subgroup has to contain the unit element.

Comment: but, $H$ is Subgroup than $\forall x \in H: (-x) \in H$ and $\forall x,y \in H: (x+y) \in H$ also $H \ni (x+(-x))=0 $ and $H \neq \emptyset$...

Comment: @Marios Actually, we have $\exists e\in H(\forall x\in H:ex = xe = x)$, rather than $H\neq\emptyset$. But in the end, with all the other axioms, either one implies the other.

Comment: @Arthur, also $H$ is Subgroup of $(G,+)$ if $\begin{cases} G \supseteq H\\ \forall x,y \in H:(x+y) \in H \\ \forall x \in H:(-x) \in H \end{cases}$ bacause I can prove $H \neq \emptyset$...????

Comment: @Marios no, you can't prove this, you have to state this: the statement $\forall x,y \in H:(x+y) \in H $ is also true in the case of $H=\emptyset$

Comment: @user190080, mmmmm if the statement $\forall x,y \in H:(x+y) \in H$ is not true in the case of $H=\emptyset$ than we have an absurd, namely $\exists x,y : x,y \in H=\emptyset \wedge (x+y) \notin H$... Is it correct?

Comment: mmmm interessant!!

Comment: @Marios maybe you find this interesting, especially the answer by Martin http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/50873/assumption-about-elements-of-the-empty-set

Comment: also habe ich richtig darüber gedacht... danke @user190080!!

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the assumption $H\ne\emptyset$ is made in the theory so that one can show that the subgroup of a group is also a group. But we neither assume from the beginning that it is a group nor for that matter that it has an identity. In other words, it is a consequence of the assumption $H\ne\emptyset$ that $H$ is a group and you can indeed use the argument given, but only if the set $H$ is nonempty since otherwise there is nothing to sum in $x+(−x)$.